# Trying add a div dynamically with giving class inside a div

Tags: javascript

i was trying to  create a div dynamically by using js method createElement() in which i am giving a class but is not working

HTML code

```
<body>
<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement('<div class="test"></div>');
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Read the documentation for [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). This is not jQuery.

Comment: function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement('div');
    btn.className = 'test';
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement('div');
    btn.classList.add('test');
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: can we do it for window event listeners also

Comment: @MujtabaHussainBhat Do what for window event listeners?

Comment: what i mean to say when i resize the window there should be crate a div or delete the div...

Answer (score 0):

`createElement` expects the tag of an element, not its actual syntax like you would write in an html page:

```js
var btn = document.createElement('div');
 btn.classList.add("test");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t1hwkt6f/1/       Can you please tell me whats wrong in this code    @torazaburo